# Discord bot detecting custom emoji in message

Tags: discord.js

I have my bot reacting to messages when messages contain a certain string, let's call it `STRING`. However, that certain string is also in the name of custom emojis, referred to as `EMOJISTRING`. I would like to be able to detect:

```
if (message.content.includes("STRING") && !message.content.includes(":EMOJISTRING:")) {
    message.react('CUSTOM_ID'); 
}
```

However, this does not work as intended, and all messages with the `STRING` still get the bot reactions, whether or not it contains `EMOJISTRING`.  Printing the incoming messages containing custom emojis to console gives `DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message`.

How should I detect a custom emoji in an incoming message by its name, e.g. `:custom_emojistring:`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this:

```
if (message.content.includes(" STRING ") && !message.content.includes(":EMOJISTRING:")) {
    message.react('CUSTOM_ID'); 
}
```

As the emojis can't have spaces at their names, that should only fetch the "STRING" you want.